# Javascript Case-Insensitive Word Frequency Counter

Tags: javascript, html, string, counter

I have a word frequency counter (similar to this site: http://www.writewords.org.uk/word_count.asp) in Javascript, but the algorithm I'm using is case-sensitive (i.e. word != Word != WORD). I can't seem to figure out how to make it ignore the case of a word. Here's the code:

```
function textCounter() {
            var pattern = /\w+/g,
                string = inputText; // inputText is a String of the text from a textarea
                matchedWords = string.match( pattern );
            var counts = matchedWords.reduce(function ( stats, word ) {
                if ( stats.hasOwnProperty( word ) ) {
                    stats[ word ] = stats[ word ] + 1;
                } else {
                    stats[ word ] = 1;
                }
                return stats;
            }, {} );          
};
```

Comment: This may help: [String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), use it as so: `string = inputText.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.